# How is it possible to get "ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationNameError" with only 1 migration file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is the setup.  Have a Ruby off Rails API application setup.

It pulls in a "database creation application" independently via git submodule.  There is a "db/migrate" folder with one migration file and a "db/structure.sql" file.  The database creation project is essentially a slimmed down Rails project - we used Rails because we needed rake tasks to let us easily migrate.

The structure.sql file essentially recreates our old database schema (we decided to keep the database code in a separate repo due to having multiple apps that need to access the database and a desire to keep the database consistent as possible).

If I do `rake db:create` I get told that `app_development` and `app_test` exist.  I've manually deleted the schema_migrations and schema_info tables from both. In fact app_test, is empty and contains no tables.

If I run rake db:migrate, I get told:

```
ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationNameError: 

Multiple migrations have the name YourMigrationToTableBlahBlah
```

How is this possible and how do I work around this error so I can migrate?

At one point I did do a git commit that renamed the columns in the 1 migration file in db/migration, but I deleted the tables in app_development and app_test as well as the schema_migrations table so the Rails rake task should not be complaining about this.

EDIT:

One thing I noticed is that during the running of `bundle exec rake db:migrate` is that the same migrations folder path (e.g., "db/migrate") is being added to `ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.migrations_paths` but I don't know why

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm facing the same issue when I update rails from 3 to 5. Same migrations are working fine in rails 3.

Comment: I did a stupid thing: have created a backup of migration files in db/migrate/tmp and got this error. After deleting my backup files, the problem wents away.

Answer (score 0):

You deleted something in the schema_migrations ,but you did not run them, and the databases still exsist in the db. Copy your schema_migrations and your data, then try to run "rake db:schema:load ". This cmd can help you rebuild the databases, and drop the data

Comment: I dropped the database and re-created it using postgres statements and it still gives the same error...

Comment: There is something wrong in "YourMigrationToTableBlahBlah", maybe you create the column or table again in "YourMigrationToTableBlahBlah"